# Leetcode answer print and answer not matching in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying out leetcode for the first time [here](https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/)

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. If I run the code locally (sanity check really), everything works as expected. If I `print` results via leetcode, I get the expected result. However, `your answer` does not match and I have no idea why.

[image]

---

I'm not asking about the solution. I know I don't need `k` for example. Returning `len(results)` would do.

---

What I don't understand is how leetcode works and what's expected in the return...

---

Notes:

- returning the results themselves fail. In that case, I got a compiler error.
- returning k, results failed too.
- the code in the screenshot is the closest I got to pass...

Comment: You simply return the number of unique values in the list. You must also modify the input list *in situ*. You are not required to print anything

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Adding the results screen as an image seems fine to me

Comment: Also, please provide the actual instructions you are given, as the exercise is otherwise only visible to logged in users.

Comment: Argh! I can't read images. They're like crosses to vampires.

Comment: >  You must also modify the input list

@Codist that's why on line 17 I've tried to add `nums = results`

Comment: @FrançoisConstant That assignment will **not** affect the input list

Comment: Oh I see. So leetcode expects you to change the input value of a function directly. That's something I avoid doing in my programs but OK, fair-enough :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the input list *in situ* then return the number of unique values in the list.

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        i = 0
        for e in nums[1:]:
            if e != nums[i]:
                i += 1
                nums[i] = e
        return i + 1
```